# Pycharm - how can I copy a file (tab) in pycharm (to a new tab)?

Tags: python, pycharm

Just got started with pycharm and was wondering how can I simply copy a file in pycharm for editing purposes? For instance, I have a file opened, want to edit the code but want to make sure that I do not accidentally "over-save" the original file.

In other environments, I can simply right click the file, and copy it to a new file. I do not see a 'copy to new file' option in pycharm, but instead I do have to manually open a new file (File>New>Python..), and then manually copy all the code from the original file and paste it in the empty new file.

Am I missing something or is that not possible in pycharm?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understood well, you are looking for to a something similar **duplicate functionality**.

So to do this, you can simply go to the project structure (the panel to the left) and copy the file in this way:

- simply Ctrl + c
- Right click on choosen file > Copy

After this, paste your file in the directory that you want in this way:

- simply Ctrl + v
- Right click on choosen directory  > Paste

In this way you have the possibility to duplicate the choosen file with another name.

Comment: Glad to help you!

Answer (score 6):

Select the file in the Project or Project Files pane and then hit File>Save as... The save-as dialog that pops up has an option (checked by default) to "open copy in editor". Not exactly what you asked for but it's the easiest way I could find.

Comment: Does the job :)